# Retrieve all basic information using FB Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i'm currently using the following api of FB Login integration in my Mobile Website : `FB.api('/me', function(response){...}` . In the resposnse i am only getting an `id` field and a `name` field. Is there any way where i can retrieve the actual `email` of the user who logs on to the site using FB Login pop up.
I read in the documentations about another URL `/{id}` , but it also returns only `id` and `name`.
Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the email of a user, you have to autorize the user with the `email` permission, and you have to add the field parameter to the API call:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=name,email', function(response){...}
```

or:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email'}, function(response){...}
```

Check out the changelog, about "Declarative Fields": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

Comment: sorry i got back late to checkout the answer , got busy outside of work.